# Coordinates given from the wrong element

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

I am trying to learn Javascript by following a guide on creating a Minesweeper game using a canvas. It's all going great apart from the fact that when I click on the options bar, it registers it as a click on the canvas.[This is a screenshot of the whole game so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwcqY.png) I can still click on the canvas and it works as it should, but clicking on the options bar (The part with the smiley face), it also registers as a click on the canvas, and removes one of the tiles.

**Here is the code that registers the mouse click:**

'

```
if(e.offsetX) {                 //Get's mouse pos relative to the canvas pos
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
}
else if(e.layerX) {
    mouseX = e.layerX;
    mouseY = e.layerY;
}

//mouseX = e.pageX;             //Gets mouse pos relatiove to page
//mouseY = e.pageY;
//console.log("Mouse Pos on screen (x, y) = " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);//Validate that the mouse position is being recorded.

//Algorithm to tell which cube the click was on.

if (Math.floor(mouseX/settings.width) < settings.columns && Math.floor(mouseY/settings.height) < settings.rows){
    clickX = Math.floor(mouseX/settings.width);
    clickY = Math.floor(mouseY/settings.height);
    console.log("Coords of clicked box (x,y)" + clickX + "," + clickY);
}
```

`

Hopefully this is enough for someone to find a problem with it, because I can't.

Comment: Can you put what you have up on codepen or jsfiddle? It'd be an awful lot easier to understand the problem that way.

Comment: @amadan http://codepen.io/LeBarryScott/pen/ZBErWp?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're capturing the click events for the whole window in one function, so whether you're clicking on the canvas or the new game div, or elsewhere in the window, you're trying to apply that click to your canvas. You'd be better advised to have a click event for the canvas itself, and another click event for the new game (which should really be a button, not a div, but I digress)

If you *really* want to carry on this way, you could explicitly limit your function to only care about your canvas. if you make gCanvas global (shudder)

```
var gCanvas = null;

function canvasLoad() {
  gCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ...
}
```

Then in your event function you can check the target of the event and only action on things that fired from your canvas

```
window.onclick = function(e){
...
 //Algorithm to tell which cube the click was on.
if (
   (e.target === gCanvas )
  )
    {
     if (Math.floor(mouseX/settings.width) < settings.columns && 
         Math.floor(mouseY/settings.height) < settings.rows)
      {
        clickX = Math.floor(mouseX/settings.width);
        clickY = Math.floor(mouseY/settings.height);
        console.log("Coords of clicked box (x,y)" + clickX + "," + clickY);
      }
    }
```

Note that this *isn't* the solution I'd go with. A tighter binding of the event to the object that fired it is much more satisfactory.

```
 <canvas id = "gameCanvas" width="153" height="153" 
         style="border:1px solid #000000;" #
         onclick='return myCanvasEventHandler()'></canvas>
```

This will explicitly limit the myCanvasEventHandler() function to fire only on events from the canvas itself.

Comment: Thanks man, the first solution works perfectly. This is my first big JS project, so I am not really concentrating on making it efficient just yet.